# JTable sort as adding and removing

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a `JTable` which I am adding so frequently. When the row number reaches the defined value which is `5000` for now, it removes the first entry and adds to the last.

This is my method which calls adding to the `model`.

```
   @Override
   public void notify( final String topic, final AvxPacket packet)
   {
      if ( this.active.get() && avionixPacket.getPacketType() == RawPacketType.AVR_PACKET )
      {
         final AVRPacket avrPacket = ( AVRPacket ) packet;

         if ( this.validateAgainstFilter( avrPacket ) )
         {
            try
            {
               this.model.addRow( AirpacketDecoder.decode( avrPacket ) );
            }
            catch ( final BadFormatException | UnspecifiedFormatError | CRCError e )
            {
               AirInspectorTable.LOG.warn( "Something went wrong", e );
            }
         }

      }
   }
```

You will see below the method which adds to rows `vector`. The `vector` is where all entries are held.

```
   /** List of table entries. */
   private final transient Vector<AirTableEntry> rows = new Vector<>();

     /** Adds an entry to table. Takes care of table size - does not let it 
     grow above defined size.
       @param airPacket data source */
   public void addRow( final AirPacket airPacket )
   {
      if ( airPacket != null )
      {
         this.rows.add( new AirTableEntry( airPacket ) );
         final int rowNumber = this.rows.size() - 1;
         this.fireTableRowsInserted( rowNumber, rowNumber );
         if ( this.rows.size() > AirTableModel.MAX_ROWS )
         {
            this.rows.remove( 0 );
            this.fireTableRowsDeleted( 0, 0 );
         }
      }
   }
```

Also I have one class named `FilterPanelEventListener` where I pass the `Table` to add a `RowSorter`.

```
/**
    * Constructor which takes source table and filterTxt as an argument.
    * @param sourceTable is the table to be modified.
    * @param sourceFilterTxt is the filter txt.
    */
   public FilterPanelEventListener( final AirInspectorTable sourceTable,
         final JTextField sourceFilterTxt )
   {
      this.table = sourceTable;
      this.filterTxt = sourceFilterTxt;
      RowSorter<? extends TableModel> rs = this.table.getRowSorter();
      this.rowSorter = new TableRowSorter<>( this.table.getModel() );

      for ( int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < this.table.getColumnCount(); rowIndex++ )
      {
         this.rowSorter.setSortable( rowIndex, false );
      }
      if ( rs == null )
      {
         this.table.setRowSorter( this.rowSorter );
         rs = this.table.getRowSorter();
      }
      this.rowSorter =
            rs instanceof TableRowSorter ? ( TableRowSorter<? extends TableModel> ) rs : null;
      if ( this.rowSorter == null )
      {
         throw new RuntimeException( "Cannot find appropriate rowSorter: " + rs );
      }
   }
```

Whenever there is an entry to a `JTextField` the `RowSorter`, sorts using this method below.

```
    /**
    * Updates the filter.
    * @param filter is the filter
    */
   private void update( final String filter )
   {
      try
      {
         if ( filter.trim().length() == 0 )
         {
            this.rowSorter.setRowFilter( null );
         }
         else
         {
            this.rowSorter
                  .setRowFilter( RowFilter.regexFilter( "(?i)" + filter, ID_COLUMN_INDEX ) );
         }
      }
      catch ( final ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex )
      {
         LOG.warn( "Something went wrong", ex );
      }
   }
```

Everything works fine until the `Vector` reaches the maximum value, sorter works perfectly. However, after maximum value, if I tend to sort(as writing something in the `JTextField`, I get dozens of exceptions, the table starts flickering. I did not notice this because my limit was normally 100000, where I actually did not wait that much it to be filled. Now I see when it is adding and removing at the same time, there is a problem. 
The exceptions are like that:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
at javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter.convertRowIndexToModel(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JTable.convertRowIndexToModel(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JTable.getValueAt(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JTable.prepareRenderer(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCell(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCells(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter.convertRowIndexToModel(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at javax.swing.JTable.convertRowIndexToModel(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at javax.swing.JTable.getValueAt(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at javax.swing.JTable.prepareRenderer(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCell(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCells(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paint(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
```

What am I doing wrong? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: 1) maybe try wrapping the delete logic in a SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...). This will add the code to the end of the Event Dispatch Thread, so hopefully all the insert logic is completely processed before the delete logic is process. 2) or may try reversing the order. Do the delete before the insert 3) do both 1 and 2.

Comment: @camickr 1) Did not work. 2) Did not work either. 3) Did not work. However, when I wrapped whole thing with SwingUtilities.invokeLater it seems to be working. Would it be causing some performence issues since this table contains 100.000 items and updated in milliseconds? Besides, is it necessarry to use SwingUtilities even for the model?

Comment: Swing is single Threaded so all updates to the model or the component should be done on the Event Dispatch Thread. The issue you where having was that some code was executing out of order so placing all the code on the EDT by using the iinvokeLater() is definitely the proper solution.

Comment: I was thinking "fireTableRowsDeleted" and "fireTableRowsInserted" was doing this automatically. In general I was thinking it was okay to not to use SwingUtilities but seems that I should be using.Thank you for your answer. I would accept it as accepted answer if you post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swing is designed to be single threaded and all updates to the model or component should be done on the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)`.

It looks like you are attempting to update the model from a separate Thread and some logic is executing out of order.

Make sure all the updates to the model are done on the `EDT` by wrapping the add/remove code in a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`.